# Unable to get expected response from nodeJs

Tags: jquery, node.js, deployment, server, vercel

```
const http = require("http");
const mailer = require("./mailer");
require("dotenv").config();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const server = http.createServer(async (req, res) => {
  if (req.url === "/formdata" && req.method === "POST") {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      "Content-Type": "text/html",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    });
    var data = "";
    await req.on("data", (chunk) => {
      data = chunk.toString();
    });

    mailer.sendMail(data, (error, resposne) => {
      if (error) {
        res.end({ error: error });
      } else {
        res.end(JSON.stringify({ response: response }));
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.end("Wrong Method or URL");
  }
});

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Running on ${port}`);
});
```

The above NodeJs code is running good when I request it from HTML file using JQuery as:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:3001/formdata",
  data: JSON.stringify($dataset),
  type: "POST",
  success: function (data) {
    // Code here
  },
})
```

But the problem is when I run it on the browser from the URL `http://localhost:3001/formdata`, it returns `Wrong Method or URL`. I also tried to deploy on vercel but the deployment shows `504: gateway_timeout code: function_invocation_timeout...`.

What is the thing i'm missing here, any help would be appreciated

**Update:**

The code was deployed successfully with getting response from the server, but i'm still curious why wouldn't it run on `http://localhost:3001/formdata`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you test route `/formdata` with POST request ?
Also do not forget to use `res.end()`

Comment: How do I tell the browser to perform a post request?

Comment: 1. I added `res.end("not mailed")` after the mailer function but it returned `Wrong Method or URL`, 2. added mailer function in `try` block and `res.end()` in `catch` block it also returned `Wrong Method or URL`, 3. commented the mailer function then it returned `not mailed`. IDK WHY ???